# Having trouble with an algorithm that loops through a string

Tags: vb.net

I am using Visual Studio Community.
Hi, I wrote a loop that loops through a string of lottery drawings.I would like to grab a full drawing and cut out the date, drawings and the Powerball numbers.

Everything works well the first time through the loop, and I get `06/29/2002 04 33 35 36 45  Powerball: 22`, but the second time through the loop I get 07/03/2002 " 04 33 35 36 45 " Powerball: 22.

The second time through the loop it goes back to the numbers for the first drawing. I know I could write

`Numbers(i) = Full_History.Substring(Start + 10, 16)`, and 
`Balls(i) = FullHistory.Substring(Start + 26, 14)`, but that doesn't seem right. I hope I explained this right. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
Dim Start As Integer = 0                                                'Create a variable for start
Dim Finish As Integer = 40                                              
For i As Integer = 0 To Array_Size - 1 Step 1                           'Loop through the string
Full_Draw(i) = Full_History.Substring(Start, Finish)                'Store the full drawing
Dates(i) = Full_History.Substring(Start, 10)                        'Store the Date of the drawing
Numbers(i) = Full_History.Substring(10, 16)                         'Store the numbers drawn
Balls(i) = Full_History.Substring(26, 14)                           'Store the 'ball' if necessary
Start += 40                                                         'Increment the start variable
```

Comment: Why doesn't "Start+10" seem right?

Comment: Thanks for all responses.Well, when I increment past the first iteration, the pointer goes to the beginning of the second iteration (the second drawing), processes the statement to store the second full_History statement and the second Dates(i) statement, but when the pointer gets to the Numbers(i) statement in the second iteration the pointer goes back to the "first" iteration (first drawing) for the Numbers(i) and the Balls(i) statement. It just doesn't seem to be right. I'm not sure if it's a logic error or a semantic error.

Answer (score 1):

If you have such specialized text you can use a [regular expression](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az24scfc%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to extract the data, like in this snippet:

```
Dim rx As New System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex("(\d\d\/\d\d\/\d{4})\s(\d\d)\s(\d\d)\s(\d\d)\s(\d\d)\s(\d\d)\s+Powerball:\s(\d\d)")
Dim s = "06/29/2002 04 33 35 36 45  Powerball: 22 06/29/2002 04 33 35 36 45  Powerball: 22 06/29/2002 04 33 35 36 45  Powerball: 22 06/29/2002 04 33 35 36 45  Powerball: 22 06/29/2002 04 33 35 36 45  Powerball: 22"
Dim matches = rx.Matches(s)
Dim sb As New System.Text.StringBuilder
For Each m As System.Text.RegularExpressions.Match In matches
    sb.AppendLine("Date: " & m.Groups(1).Value)
    sb.AppendLine("#1: " & m.Groups(2).Value)
    sb.AppendLine("#2: " & m.Groups(3).Value)
    sb.AppendLine("#3: " & m.Groups(4).Value)
    sb.AppendLine("#4: " & m.Groups(5).Value)
    sb.AppendLine("#5: " & m.Groups(6).Value)
    sb.AppendLine("Powerball: " & m.Groups(7).Value)
    sb.AppendLine()
Next
MessageBox.Show(sb.ToString)
```

Granted it is not the most elegent RegEx ever, but it should be easy enough to follow:

- \d stands for a single digit
- / is the literal slash character
- {4} is a quantifier, meaning 4 of the previous thing
- /s is whitespace
- /s+ means as much whitespace as you like
- () denote capturing groups, allowing the access to the values in the .Groups property of each match

So you find all matches in a given text and can easily extract all subgroups by iterating over the matches.

---

For your general question:

```
Numbers(i) = Full_History.Substring(10, 16)                         'Store the numbers drawn
Balls(i) = Full_History.Substring(26, 14)
```

These lines will always crop the same part out of the source string (e.g. index 10 to 26). You need to scale the Substring start part with the `Start` variable as well, like

```
Numbers(i) = Full_History.Substring(Start + 10, 16)                         'Store the numbers drawn
Balls(i) = Full_History.Substring(Start + 26, 14)
```

Otherwise it is not suprising that each element ends up the same. Or to avoid more confusion, first crop the whole thing out and then dissect this new string into its parts:

```
For i As Integer = 0 To Array_Size - 1 Step 1                           'Loop through the string
    Dim ThisDraw As String = Full_History.Substring(Start, Finish)
    Full_Draw(i) = ThisDraw
    'Notice the fixed indizes now
    Dates(i) = ThisDraw.Substring(0, 10)                        'Store the Date of the drawing
    Numbers(i) = ThisDraw.Substring(10, 16)                         'Store the numbers drawn
    Balls(i) = ThisDraw.Substring(26, 14)                           'Store the 'ball' if necessary
    Start += Finish
Next
```

Comment: I have coded in the Full_Draw(i) = Full_History.Substring(Start + 10, 10), etc, but it still seems strange that the second time through the loop I have to go back and code as if it was in the first iteration. But it works.

Comment: @JimConace I have not really said why your approach failed, you are right about this. See my edited answer that should illustrate the problem.

Answer (score 0):

thank you for your responses. I fixed the issue by cutting out a single drawing in an array, and then cutting a substring (single Drawing) out of that, instead of trying to cut the Drawings, Dates, Numbers and Balls out of the "FullString" array straight from the stream.

Thanks for all the help
Jim